# combobox: send values of valueField and displayField to server in update

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs5

Consider an app with a grid, a form and a window.

If I select a grid row the record data (detail) is displayed in form (binding).

With dblclick event in grid row a window with form is displayed to update the record, and fields are filled (binding).

The form on window has a combobox that has a store and the value of the field to update is filled by binding.

My issue:

I need to send combobox valueField and displayField to server in update (the id and cars value) simultaneously.

Is there any way to do this directly with a combobox config or adding, in some way, another bind/value?

```
xtype: 'combobox',
fieldLabel: 'myField',
name:'id', 
bind: {
    store: '{mystore}',
    value: '{record.id}' //load value from record to update and bind (to display in grid and form)
},
displayField:'cars',
valueField:'id',
queryMode: 'local',
```

EDITED:

One solution I usually use, which requires the use of a method or event, is:

```
    var values = myForm.getValues();
    var comboValue = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#mycomboItenmId')[0].getRawValue();

    var objCombosValue = {
         'combo_value': comboValue
     }

     var allValues = Ext.Object.merge(values, objCombosValue);

     record.set(allValues);

     store.sync({})
```

Is there any pure binding solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending the values to the server via store sync()? You could add a new field to the model to hold the displayField value and update that field on the 'select' event of the combo box.

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar Fabio. One solution I have used is to add a kind of extaparameters before the sync method that work's well (I edited my post); however, what I intended was to send the values without needing to use any event or method. Mabe with 'pure binding'.